# Уместное использование пространства при Metro стиле

Tags: дизайн, веб-дизайн

Здравствуйте!

Создаю личный сайт-одностраничник в стилях Metro и Mini (стили, как в windows 10 и IOS). Дошёл до части, где нужно разместить информацию о себе. Но тут проблема: не могу придумать, как красиво оформить эту часть сайта.

Я взял и разместил текст с левой части и выровнял его по середине по вертикале. Потом решил справа вставить картинку "соответствующую" части "О себе". Но выглядит это не красиво. Может кто-то предложит идею, как можно в выше перечисленных стилях оформить данную часть сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Юрий, ну вот вы давний пользователь сайта и должны же прекрасно понимать, что вопрос нужно формулировать так, чтобы дать объективно верный ответ. Накидайте идей -- это не объективно по умолчанию, вы же не можете на каждую галку поставить. И не озвучиваете, какие у вас критерии красоты (они вообще трудно формализуемы). [Не надо так](http://graphnet.ru/images/1867651_kartinka-iz-kontakta-ne-nado-tak.jpg).

Comment: @AK, как по мне всё ясно изложил: одностраничник, блок "о себе", стили metro - mini, приложил фотографию для ориентации стиля. Ответ принял потом, что она мне понравился и натолкнул на идею, как можно ещё лучше сделать

Comment: @Yuri - вы на самом деле Павел Дуров?

Comment: @Vadizar, пфффф... конечно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно разместить фото так-же в центре и сделать заливку блока темно-серую.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]